# How to assign value to google map marker array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to assign an array to a marker in the javascript function below.  It does not work with push, or with the commented out statement either.  I am not sure if a map marker is allowed to have an array.  The marker.mycategory works fine, it is only the array that doesn't work.

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, html, category, animals) 
  {

      var markerImg = setMarker(category);

      var contentString = html;

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          title: name,
          icon: markerImg,
          });

      for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++)
          marker.myanimals.push(animals[i]); 
          //marker.myanimals[i] = animals[i];

      marker.mycategory = category;                                 
      marker.myname = name;

      gmarkers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
          });

  } // end createMarker()
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a `marker.myanimals = [];` before your for loop, than it should work

Answer (score 1):

[google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) extends [google.maps.MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject), so it will be good ,that you use the methods of `MVCObject`.

Instead of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++)
      marker.myanimals.push(animals[i]); 
      //marker.myanimals[i] = animals[i];

  marker.mycategory = category;                                 
  marker.myname = name;
```

Use :

```
marker.setValues({
   mycategory : category,
   myname : name,
   myanimals : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(animals))  //Deep copy of 'animals' array
});
```

And to access property, use `get` method ( e.g. `marker.get('mycategory')` ).